# How to flatten a numpy slice?

Tags: python, numpy

I am implementing a subclass of numpy's ndarray and I need to modify `__getitem__` to fetch items from a flattened representation of the array. The problem is that `__getitem__` can either be called with an integer index or a multidimensional slice.

Does any one know how to convert a multidimensional slice to a list of indices (or a uni-dimensional slice) on the flattened array?

Answer (score 3):

It may not be possible to convert a multidimensional slice to a flat slice, e.g.:

```
>>> a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> a[::3, 1::2]
array([[ 1,  3],
       [13, 15]])
```

And you cannot access the subarray `[ 1,  3, 13, 15]` with a `start:stop:step` notation. But you can construct a list of flat indices from multidimensional ones, doing something like the following:

```
>>> row_idx = np.arange(4)[::3]
>>> col_idx = np.arange(4)[1::2]
>>> row_idx = np.repeat(row_idx, 2)
>>> col_idx = np.tile(col_idx, 2)
>>> np.ravel_multi_index((row_idx, col_idx), dims=(4,4))
array([ 1,  3, 13, 15], dtype=int64)
```

---

In a more general setting, once you have an array of indices for each dimension, you need to buld the cartesian product of all index arrays, so `itertools.product` is probably the way to go. For example:

```
>>> indices = [np.array([0, 4, 8]), np.array([1,7]), np.array([3, 5, 9])]
>>> indices = zip(*itertools.product(*indices))
>>> indices
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8),
 (1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7),
 (3, 5, 9, 3, 5, 9, 3, 5, 9, 3, 5, 9, 3, 5, 9, 3, 5, 9)]
>>> np.ravel_multi_index(indices, dims=(10, 11, 12))
array([  15,   17,   21,   87,   89,   93,  543,  545,  549,  615,  617,
        621, 1071, 1073, 1077, 1143, 1145, 1149], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Very interesting, to generalize this, you need to know the shape of your matrix (easy) and how many steps of your stride will fit in your matrix (for the repeat and tile functions).  The second pre-requisite is not so straightforward but should be doable.

Comment: @fccoelho It isn't that complicated, I think `row_idx = np.repeat(row_idx, len(col_idx))` and `col_idx = np.tile(col_idx, len(row_idx))` is what you need to generalize the above approach.

Comment: One other issue: if a matrix is more than 2d what axis do we use to extend each index, for example suppose our original matrix 4x4x4x4? And should extend them with tile or repeat?